# Why does asterisk produce unexpected results in find?

Tags: command-line, bash, find

I'm new to Bash. From the [Finding Files documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FindingFiles):

> You want to find every file in ~/mydir and all its subdirectories, recursively, with a file extension of .htm (or .HTM or .Htm...) and delete it. I've seen a lot of attempts like rm -rf ~/mydir/*.htm which really don't come close. The correct solution is
>
> ```
> find ~/mydir -iname '*.htm' -exec rm {} \;
> ```
>
> `-iname` says that you want to do a case-insensitive search on the filename. `'*.htm'` is in single quotes to prevent bash from expanding the *, which will produce unexpected results.

---

**Question:** What does asterisk produce with and without the quotes? Why would you decide to use quotes versus not?

Comment: If you really would like to delete files, you would use `find ~/mydir -iname -type f "*.htm" -delete`, since Ubuntu uses gnu-find, which has the handy -delete switch. Simpler for typing, and find will, if you omit the -type f restriction, start a deep-first-search, and eventually delete empty directories, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without quotes, the shell expands `*.htm` to a list of files and passes this list to `find`.  With quotes, the shell provides the five character string `*.htm` as an argument to `find`.

For example, with quotes:

```
$ ls
a.htm  b.htm
$ echo find . -iname '*.htm'
find . -iname *.htm
$ find . -iname '*.htm'
./b.htm
./a.htm
```

The above works as desired.  Without quotes, `find` is given arguments that it does not know how to process:

```
$ echo find . -iname *.htm
find . -iname a.htm b.htm
$ find . -iname *.htm
find: paths must precede expression: b.htm
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about an example first, here we are looking for all files with `.htm` extension (case insensitive) recursively :

```
$ tree 
.
├── spam
│   ├── egg.htm
│   └── egg.Htm
├── spam.htm
└── spam.Htm


$ find . -type f -iname *.htm
./spam.htm
./spam.Htm

$ find . -type f -iname '*.htm'
./spam.htm
./spam/egg.htm
./spam/egg.Htm
./spam.Htm
```

As you can see in the first case where i have not used any quoting `-iname *.htm`, the filename has been subjected to glob (`*`) expansion first (done by shell, before `find` starts) as i have not used any quote and result in :

```
find . -type f -iname spam.htm spam.Htm
```

i.e. all files in the current directory having an extension `.htm` (case insensitive). As a result although `./spam` subdirectory has two files with `.htm` extension but they won't be found as we are now looking for files `spam.htm` or `spam.Htm`.

On the other hand in the second case `find . -type f -iname '*.htm'`, we have used quoting so the filenames won't be subjected to glob expansion hence we will get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are seeking to understand is a process called Quoting. Quoting works with double quotes and single quotes.

If you place text inside double quotes, all special characters used by the shell lose their meaning, except $ (dollar sign), \ (backslash), and ` (back tick).

Single quotes suppress all expansions.

Escaping Characters are also something to be given attention in such situations. You can precede a character with a \ (backslash) to turn it into an Escaping Character. This is often done inside double quotes to selectively prevent an expansion.

```
echo "This bowl costs \$10.00"
This bowl costs $10.00
```

Here $ would be said to be the Escape Character.